# How to reset all flags in 8085 without an arithmetic or logic operation?

Tags: microprocessor, intel, 8085

How can I reset all flags in 8085 without an arithmetic or logic operation?

Comment: How about a hardware reset or power cycle/glitch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the old hacker/DYI debugger trick of mismatched stack push/pop operations, to directly set the flags register.

```
; terrible hack loads A and Flags
; regs D and E are used as temporary
MVI D, #___ ; move immediate value for A
MVI E, #___ ; move immediate value for Flags SZIH-P-C
PUSH DE ; temporary
POP PSW ; pop A and Flags
```

Similar technique can be used in DIY debugger code, to read the flags:

```
; read the flags from processor status word
; regs D and E are used as temporary
PUSH PSW
POP DE
; now E = value of Flags SZIH-P-C
```

It's usually simpler and more direct to just use arithmetic or logic instructions -- such as `ANI #FF` boolean AND immediate with all ones to re-evaluate Sign, Zero, Parity, Carry flags. This is much better programming practice, since it avoids using up valuable register resources, and is what programmers are accustomed to seeing. Readability is very important in programming and debugging.